# search posts with blogger api v3 in specific date range

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

If we want to search google blogger posts with blogger APIs v3, then we should follow the documentation in [here](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/search). But how can we integrate a date range in query parameter `q`? i tried `q=startDate:2016-01-01:T00:00:00+endDate:2017-09-05:T00:00:00` but it doesn't work.

I also tried to search posts from a certain date and after by using `q=startDate:2016-01-01:T00:00:00` or `q=startDate:"2016-01-01:T00:00:00"` or `q=startDate:2016-01-01`  but still doesn't work. The URL encoding is done properly because I tested with labels search like `q=label:symbols|label:fonts` for searching posts which contain either the label `symbols` or the label `fonts` and it works just fine.

Comment: What to use for the updated field?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of search i finally find out that the answer was there but i was not looking carefully. When we want to search posts in a specific date range, we do not query the [search:posts](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list) operation but the [list:posts](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/reference/posts/list) operation. For example if we want to search from `October 2, 2016` to `September 7, 2017` we send a request url of the following form:

`https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/{blogID}/posts?
startDate=2016-10-02T00:00:00z&endDate=2017-09-07T00:00:00z
&callback=handleResponse&key={our_received_key}`

`handleResponse` is the callback function which is called when the response is received successfully. The above url query is ineffective because we receive also the body text of the post, which can impact performance. Also pagination must be used. The first is achieved by setting the `fetchBodies=false` and the second is achieved by using `maxResults` and `pageToken`.

A simplified script which encapsulates the above comments can be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Blogger API Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script>
        function handleResponse(response) {
            var post = "";
            for (var i in response.items)
            {
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<a href=\"" + response.items[i].url +
                    "\">" + response.items[i].title + "</a>" + "<br/>";
            }
      }
    </script>
    <script src='https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/35636577512/posts?startDate=2016-10-02T00:00:00z&endDate=2017-09-07T00:00:00z&maxResults=10&fetchBodies=false&callback=handleResponse&key=RTza3456gfhf_Q345fgh'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

if the total number of posts is greater than the maxResults which is 10 in the example, then a `nextPageToken` will be sent which can be retrieved by `response.nextPageToken` and stored in the next url query.

`https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/35636577512/posts?startDate=2008-10-02T00:00:00z&endDate=2016-09-06T17:30:00z&pageToken=dfgdfRtdfdf234rT&fetchBodies=false&callback=handleResponse&key=RTza3456gfhf_Q345fgh'`